VoxelGI Godot C#
I'm trying to extract VoxelGI data to process the computed lighting information.
I've attached a C# script to a VoxelGI instance and can access the VoxelGI data. However, the documentation is very unclear about what this data structure means.
What I need is x, y, z coordinates of the VoxelGI probes and their lighting information.
How would I extract this information from the VoxelGIData? Is there a resource to better understand what the datastructure contains?
